# Force one include file to be included before another

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

Imagine I have two `.hpp` files:

```
#ifndef _DEF_FILE_1_
#define _DEF_FILE_1_
inline void some_function_1(){
    /*do stuff*/
}
#endif
```

and

```
#ifndef _DEF_FILE_2_
#define _DEF_FILE_2_
#ifdef _DEF_FILE_1_
inline void some_function_2(){
    /*do stuff using some_function_1()*/
}
#else
inline void some_function_2(){
    /*do the same stuff without using some_function_1()*/
}
#endif
#endif
```

My problem arises when I don't know in which order the files are included, e.g:
in the `main.cpp` i can have something like :

```
#include "file1.hpp"
#include "file2.hpp"
int main(){
    some_function_2();
    /*will call the function that uses some_function_1()*/
}
```

or

```
#include "file2.hpp"
#include "file1.hpp"
int main(){
    some_function_2();
    /*will call the function that doesn't use some_function_1()*/
}
```

Is there a way to make sure that as soon as both `file1.hpp` and `file2.hpp`
are included, then `some_function_2()` will call `some_function_1()`?

PS: One solution would be to include `file1.hpp` in `file2.hpp` but I can't do
that because I developp a code that may or may not depend on some library
that the end-user may or may not have.

PPS: The only other solution I can think of (even if I don't know how to
achieve this) would be to "delete" the definition of `some_method_2()` when
`file1.hpp` is included and then reinclude `file2.hpp`.

Comment: AFAIK you can only instruct the users to include the header before yours, the preprocessor will go through the files in order and you can't really do anything about things that might follow your header.

Comment: Why don't you make a third header, in which you `include` them in the right order, and use it in `main.cpp`? Nice username, btw.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Thx, my favourite band ;-). Because I don't know if the end-user has `file1.hpp`.

Comment: OT: Your include guards are [illegal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @BaummitAugen: thanks, I was not aware of that

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea. You can very easily break the ODR and you don't really have very good control over which function implementation will be used. Why do you think you need to do this? There _must_ be a better way...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit add `static` to get round likely ODR violations I think.  Still a bad idea.

Comment: Pink, are the functions actually 0 argument functions?  This matters.

Comment: @Yakk, no, this was an example... I have many different function, with different arguments. I also have templates, classes...

Comment: @PinkFloyd Then the arguments can matter, as can the namespaces.  ADL lookup is deferred to the point of template instantiation, while non-ADL lookup is done at template definition.  Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I believe proper solution would be to rewrite `some_function_2()` using SFINAE mechanism and template instead of preprocessor tricks. That way instantiation will happen in cpp file where it would be known if `some_function_1()` exists and order of include will not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your users should know if they have "some library" or, you should have some way of determining if that library is present. So you could do something like:

In file2.hpp

```
#ifndef _DEF_FILE_2_
#define _DEF_FILE_2_
#ifdef _DEF_HAS_SOME_LIBRARY_
#include "file1.hpp"
inline void some_function_2(){
    /*do stuff using some_function_1()*/
}
#else
inline void some_function_2(){
    /*do the same stuff without using some_function_1()*/
}
#endif
#endif
```

Or if possible eliminate file1.hpp entirely, and put `some_function_1()` in the location of `#include "file1.hpp"` above.

Now main.cpp should only include file2.hpp.

```
// optionally #define _DEF_HAS_SOME_LIBRARY_
#include "file2.hpp"
int main(){
    some_function_2();
    /*will call the function that uses some_function_1()*/
}
```

though, a solution that avoids the preprocessor would be better in my opinion.

Comment: What do you mean by `_DEF_HAS_SOME_LIBRARY_`, how can I check that ?

Comment: You say the problem is that "you don't know the order of the files included", but someone must know. Either you have an alternate means of determining if some_library is accessible on the machine, or whoever is trying to include "file2.hpp" has that knowledge. Before including "file2.hpp" the user of "file2.hpp" should either define _DEF_HAS_SOME_LIBRARY_ or not depending on whether or not they want the functionality enabled of some library.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know whether the file exists and need to handle that, well, neither c nor c++ preprocessor handle file existence checks. This is one of the reasons behind configure tools.

You need to probe for this information beforehand, and set it before compiling. There many ways to do it. Usually a tool / script, creates some `configure.h` header with appropriate defines is created. E.g. containing such line `#define FILE1_HPP_EXISTS 1`.

Then you can always rely on presence of `configure.h` and it will provide information you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler allows it you might use the `_has_include` macro:

Just change you `file2.hpp` to:

```
#ifndef _DEF_FILE_2_
#define _DEF_FILE_2_

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include("file1.hpp")
# include "file1.hpp"
inline void some_function_2() {
    /*do stuff using some_function_1()*/
}
#else
inline void some_function_2() {
    /*do the same stuff without using some_function_1()*/
}
#endif
#endif
```

But keep in mind that this is a compiler specific extension.